# How to get the raw SQL query from a SQLAlchemy query with selectinload option

Tags: python, sql, debugging, join, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the raw SQL query that is used by SQL Alchemy when using the `selectinload` option.

Normally `print(stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))` gives you the statement that will be executed, but when using `selectinload` this does not work as it only produces the raw SQL used to get the first item in the select.

How do I do this in my code, similar to `print(stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))`, without needing to turn on echoing of all queries the are produced and executed by SQLAlchemy.

Consider the following example:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sql
from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload
from db import Sessionmaker
from models import VatOrder
from config import logger

def get(vat_order_id: int) -> VatOrder| None:
    stmt = sql.select(VatOrder)
        .options(selectinload(VatOrder.vat_order_details))
        .where(VatOrder.id == vat_order_id)
    # Stop debugger here
    session = Sessionmaker()
    try:
        return session.scalar(stmt)
    except DBAPIError as e:
        logger.error("Error while getting VAT order %s", e)
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Normally i'd use a debugger on the the line `# Stop debugger here` and do `print(stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))` to get the raw sql query. But when using `selectinload` option I only get returned for example:

```sql
SELECT vatorder.id, vatorder.period, vatorder.country, vatorder.currency, vatorder.customer_id, vatorder.amount, vatorder.year
FROM vatorder
WHERE vatorder.idbtworder = 3711453
```

I can turn on echo in sqlalchemy to show all queries that are being executed, however I am looking for a similar way to `stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})` for debugging purposes.

Comment: I don't think that there's a way to do this.